# Failed to build with colcon: "cannot import name 'has_ros_schema_reference'"

Tags: ros, ros2, colcon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Having a clean workspace with single empty folder `src`  , I source ROS2 by calling
`source /opt/ros/dashing/setup.bash` and running `colcon build` I get an exception in colcon core package (or catkin_pkg package ?) as displayed below:

```
[0.164s] ERROR:colcon.colcon_core.package_identification:Exception in package identification extension 'ros' in '/home/yossi/temp_ws': cannot import name 'has_ros_schema_reference'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_core/package_identification/__init__.py", line 143, in _identify
    retval = extension.identify(_reused_descriptor_instance)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_ros/package_identification/ros.py", line 59, in identify
    pkg, build_type = get_package_with_build_type(str(desc.path))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_ros/package_identification/ros.py", line 163, in get_package_with_build_type
    pkg = _get_package(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_ros/package_identification/ros.py", line 171, in _get_package
    from catkin_pkg.package import has_ros_schema_reference
ImportError: cannot import name 'has_ros_schema_reference'

[0.166s] ERROR:colcon.colcon_core.package_identification:Exception in package identification extension 'ros' in '/home/yossi/temp_ws/src': cannot import name 'has_ros_schema_reference'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_core/package_identification/__init__.py", line 143, in _identify
    retval = extension.identify(_reused_descriptor_instance)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_ros/package_identification/ros.py", line 59, in identify
    pkg, build_type = get_package_with_build_type(str(desc.path))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_ros/package_identification/ros.py", line 163, in get_package_with_build_type
    pkg = _get_package(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_ros/package_identification/ros.py", line 171, in _get_package
    from catkin_pkg.package import has_ros_schema_reference
ImportError: cannot import name 'has_ros_schema_reference'

                     
Summary: 0 packages finished [0.08s]
```

I've tried to purge and reinstall ALL packages relevant to ROS1, ROS2, colcon, catkin but that did not help.

**In fact, having ROS2 uninstalled and trying to run `colcon build` in the same workspace yields the same error.**

The problem started to occur at some point couple days ago, before that I used this system for several months for both ROS1 and ROS2 development.

Any ideas what could have happen to it and is there a way to solve it before reinstalling the whole system?

**Additional information**:

```
└─▶ $ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Relevant environment variables:

```
└─▶ $ printenv | grep -i -e ROS -e CATKIN -e CMAKE -e RMW
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/ros/dashing/opt/yaml_cpp_vendor/lib:/opt/ros/dashing/opt/rviz_ogre_vendor/lib:/opt/ros/dashing/lib:/opt/rti.com/rti_connext_dds-5.3.1/lib/x64Linux3gcc5.4.0
AMENT_PREFIX_PATH=/opt/ros/dashing
ROS_VERSION=2
ROS_PYTHON_VERSION=3
PYTHONPATH=/opt/ros/dashing/lib/python3.6/site-packages
PATH=/opt/ros/dashing/bin:/opt/rti.com/rti_connext_dds-5.3.1/lib/x64Linux3gcc5.4.0:/opt/rti.com/rti_connext_dds-5.3.1/bin:/home/yossi/ardupilot/Tools/autotest:/opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q3/bin:/home/yossi/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/yossi/.dotnet/tools
ROS_DISTRO=dashing
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/339552/failed-to-build-with-colcon:-%22cannot-import-name-%27has_ros_schema_reference%27%22/) by [yossi_ov](https://answers.ros.org/users/31601/yossi_ov/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2019-12-10

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) on 2019-12-10**:
Could you share your versions of `colcon-ros` and `catkin-pkg-modules`?

You need catkin_pkg(_modules) >= 0.4.14 for the has_ros_schema_reference function to exist

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2019-12-10**:
Please post the output of `dpkg -l | grep catkin-pkg` as well as `python3 -c "import catkin_pkg; print(catkin_pkg.__version__)"`.

**Comment by [yossi_ov](https://answers.ros.org/users/31601/yossi_ov/) on 2019-12-11**:
Unfortunately I had to reformat the computer and can't check anything anymore

@marguedas It was latest updated by `apt`

@clyde That's the one option I haven't tried. Probably that could solve it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I ran into this a few days ago. The problem turned out to be an older version of catkin_pkg/package.py installed by `pip3 install` hiding the just released version installed by `apt install`. I cleaned up my Python environment and the problem went away.

---

Originally posted by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) with karma: 1247 on 2019-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) on 2019-12-13**:
Thanks! This fixed the issue for me too. For anyone trying to decide if this the same issue, run `python3 -c "import catkin_pkg; import inspect; print(inspect.getfile(catkin_pkg))"`. On Ubuntu bionic that should print `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/__init__.py`. If you get any other path it means `catkin_pkg` is being imported from somewhere else, probably a pip install. Remove it with `pip3 uninstall catkin_pkg`.